# Why won't ubuntu on a wireless internet connection work with Panera bread or other hotspots

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I currently am running Ubuntu 9.04 and have a wireless card installed with the correct driver.  When I try to connect to a public hotspot sometimes the connection works and sometimes it doesn't.  Do these public hotspots use some kind of proxy that isn't compatible with the wireless card?

Thank YOu,
Ruben

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the hotspots use special modes or security settings that are not supported in the linux driver. Can you access these same hotspots in Windows?

Comment: Yes, I can access the hotspots in windows.  Also, I can't even get to the initial login screen.

Comment: The initial login screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem myself. Everywhere else I can access hotspots with Lucid, but not at Panera Bread for some reason. I have a dualbooted win7/lucid laptop and win7 doesn't have connectivity problems; lucid does. I think the router might

1. either not trust linux systems (highly unlikely)
2. not accept wifi adapters in promiscuous mode (which, IIRC, is the default for Ubuntu). I'm going to try changing this and report if it helps any. Also, if you did something to correct this, let me know if you can.